# Change connection string of datasource on build for SSRS Project

Tags: reporting-services

I have a few SSRS projects and when I publish the projects, I have to manually go back to Reporting Services and change back the connection string to the correct server. 
Is there a way to automate this? Can I change the connection string on build (before publish) base on my configuration?

Comment: Is this for a shared data source or embeded within your report?

Comment: There are multiple projects in each a shared data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to assume a few things here..

1. Your Report has a Datasource called something like Datasource_dev
2. You are attempting to deploy to different environments that have different datasources like Datasource_test and Datasource_Prod?

If the above conditions are true, then you simply have to set the correct datasource ***once*** on each of the servers you are deploying to ie, the first time you deploy the report.

You will also need to set the setting below (in properties of your SSRS project) to

- OverwriteDataSources=false

Then all subsequent deployments will retain the datasource that was set manually.

Couple of things to Note.

- Make sure you change the setting for all configurations you have (debug,release etc)
- If you ever delete the report from the server, you'll have to reset the datasource again

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a way to fully automate it. But did you try to just create a Data source? Then just edit the Data Source connection of the report under Manage? In that way you don't have to go back to SSRS when you will just edit the connection of the report.

Comment: :) Obviously, this is the way to work if you have one server. We have 4-5 different environments. So, it's a pain change it in this manner for 10 projects. Hence, the question is really about **how** to automate it, not how to do it manually.